# Only display values that exist in two data-pools using EXIST statement

Tags: sql, postgresql

**[DB-Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=f3cda57dae187666aa1ff9d5cbebc6e9)**

```
CREATE TABLE sales (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    sales_date DATE,
    customer VARCHAR(255)
);

INSERT INTO sales
(sales_date, customer)
VALUES 
('2020-01-17', 'customer_01'),
('2020-01-19', 'customer_02'),
('2020-01-20', 'customer_02'),
('2020-01-22', 'customer_03'),

('2021-01-04', 'customer_05'),
('2021-01-11', 'customer_01'),
('2021-01-15', 'customer_03'),
('2021-01-22', 'customer_03'),
('2021-01-31', 'customer_04');
```

**Expected Result:**

```
sales_date  |    customer   | 
------------|---------------|-----
2021-01-11  |  customer_01  | 
2021-01-15  |  customer_03  |
2021-01-22  |  customer_03  |
```

---

I want to query all customers that appear in the period `BETWEEN '2021-01-01' AND '2021-01-31'` and also exist in the period `BETWEEN '2020-01-01' AND '2020-01-31'` therefore I tried to go with this query:

```
SELECT
t1.sales_date,
t1.customer
FROM 

  (SELECT
   sales_date,
   customer
   FROM sales
   WHERE sales_date BETWEEN '2021-01-01' AND '2021-01-31') t1

WHERE EXISTS

  (SELECT
   customer
   FROM sales
   WHERE sales_date BETWEEN '2020-01-01' AND '2020-01-31')
    
ORDER BY 2;
```

The result of this query includes the `customer_04` and `customer_05` although they do not appear `BETWEEN '2020-01-01' AND '2020-01-31'`.

Therefore, someowh the `EXIST` statement is compeletly ignored. 
How do I need to modify it to make it work?

---

*I know I could solve the specific case above by joining the the two tables instead of using EXIST. 
 However, in my original database I need to use EXIST so I am looking for a solution with the EXIST statement.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query should be dependent on the specific value from t1. Add the condition "AND s.customer = t1.customer".

```
SELECT
t1.sales_date,
t1.customer
FROM 

  (SELECT
   sales_date,
   customer
   FROM sales
   WHERE sales_date BETWEEN '2021-01-01' AND '2021-01-31') t1

WHERE EXISTS

  (SELECT
   customer 
   FROM sales s
   WHERE sales_date BETWEEN '2020-01-01' AND '2020-01-31'
     AND s.customer = t1.customer)
    
ORDER BY 2;
```

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=738cc75ebfb8980b3c524344d9f16beb

Comment: Just for my own documentation: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=8efd851d7c1d00897b044eda74a2186f

Answer (score 0):

The EXISTS operator is a boolean operator that tests for existence of rows in a subquery.

> someowh the EXIST statement is compeletly ignored

```
WHERE EXISTS

  (SELECT
   customer
   FROM sales
   WHERE sales_date BETWEEN '2020-01-01' AND '2020-01-31')
```

That why the above where condition become true and returned all the rows from sales_date BETWEEN '2021-01-01' AND '2021-01-31' in  your code.

As joe suggested we must add dependant column to overcome the issue.  Hers's my code

```
SELECT
   sales_date,
   customer
   FROM sales a
WHERE EXISTS
  (SELECT
   1
   FROM sales b
   WHERE a.customer = b.customer and sales_date  BETWEEN '2020-01-01' AND '2020-01-31'
   )
and  a.sales_date  BETWEEN '2021-01-01' AND '2021-01-31'   
ORDER BY 2;
```